# How Ruby Is Run

Tags: ruby, scripting, applescript

I come from an object oriented programming background, and have picked up Ruby as a hobby. It looks like a great language. My questions are:

1. Can you use any ol' test editor, write your ruby file, save it with a .rb extension and open it in the terminal?
2. Is this the most common method of using Ruby (Or other script languages), rather than with an IDE?
3. How do I close external programs on my Mac with ruby? What I will be doing with Ruby has a lot to do with opening files and commanding them. I was using AppleScript but want to convert. I've tried:

   `system open "John/Applications/TextEdit.app"`

And it didn't close.

Comment: why do people vote to close this question and don't give a comment on how to improve the question ?

Comment: I haven't voted (yet), but I think the question is too broad. Multiple questions in one are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it makes it difficult to concisely answer them all in an answer, which dilutes the value of the question itself. Instead one question alone is preferred, or two very closely related questions are acceptable. The first two questions here are remotely related by editors, but the third isn't related at all. Please reduce the question to one, and ask your other ones in separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Windows but I'll try to answer your questions as good as possible, most of the stuff is OS independent.

For questions 1 and 2: You can use one of the following ways to edit and run Ruby scripts.

- IRB (Interactive RuBy shell included with Ruby)
- websites like http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0
- An IDE such as:

  - RedMine
  - KomodoEdit
  - Eclipse with plugin (not that easy to configure)
    not really necessary because Ruby code is short and easy to remember, kind of pseudocode, the advantage is in the beginning when you don't know the commands and structures and for debugging
    voordeel = debuggen is makkelijker
- Editor with a Run-optie like Textpad, Notepad++, Sublime Text..
  The last one is my favorite, there are packages for Ruby but Ruby support is in the basic installation, you can edit your code with syntax-coloring and suggestions, run your code and the result is captured in a separate tab. It is the most widely used way of Ruby coding also.

  3. In Windows I use the following way to run external programs and capture the result. I believe it to be working on a Mac also. The external shell and program is closed after the last end.

     ```
     answer = ""
     command = %Q{java -jar test.jar #{$parameter1} #{$parameter2}"}
     IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |pipe|
     pipe.sync = true
       while str = pipe.gets
         answer << str
       end
     end
     #the answer variable holds all the output lines
     ```

Comment: Two of the most common editors for programming, independent of programming language or OS, are Vim and EMACS. There are more people using them because they are available on a huge number of systems and work the same, whether you are on Windows, Mac, *nix or mainframes.